# Iterate Counter Inside jQuery .each() Loop

Tags: jquery, each

I need to increment a `var` counter inside an `$.each()` loop. Here's my code:

```
ajaxCreateOrder = function(fileUrl, dataArray, numRecords) {
    var loopIteration = 1;
    var ajaxIterateDelay = 1000;
    $.each(dataArray, function(key,val) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            doAjaxRequest(loopIteration, fileUrl, val, numRecords);
        }, loopIteration * ajaxIterateDelay);
        loopIteration++;
    });
}
```

All is working as expected, except that `loopIteration` does not increment. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [wrong use of a closure variable in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)

```
ajaxCreateOrder = function (fileUrl, dataArray, numRecords, storeView) {
    var ajaxIterateDelay = 1000;
    $.each(dataArray, function (index, val) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            doAjaxRequest(index + 1, fileUrl, val, numRecords);
        }, (index + 1) * ajaxIterateDelay);
    });
}
```

Assuming `dataArray` is an array, the first argument is the `index`, you can use it

Comment: _It is because of wrong use of a closure variable in loop_ - It's just a simple multiplication to get the timeout for `setTimeout`. There is no variable which is evaluated when the loop has finished...

Comment: @Andreas `loopIteration` is used inside the `setTimeout()` which pauses a problem because it will have the last value of the loop

Comment: @Andreas [problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7AM2u/2/) [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7AM2u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        // ...
        loopIteration++;                   // inside
    }, loopIteration * ajaxIterateDelay);
                                           // not here
```

Comment: Thank you, that could be it :)